# How to fix message id coming from kafka-mongo-connector set up as source

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am trying to add kafka-mongo-connector to kafka-connect to be the source of the events. I am setting up the connector like this:

```
{"name": "mongo-source",
  "config": {
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "connector.class":"com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri":"mongodb://mongo1:27017,mongo2:27017,mongo3:27017",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JSONSerializer",
    "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.JSONSerializer",
    "key.serializer.schemas.enable": "false",
    "value.serializer.schemas.enable": "false",
    "topic.prefix":"mongo",
     "database":"test",
     "collection":"pageviews"
}}' http://localhost:8083/connectors -w "\n"
```

Data is coming in but the key is in weird format: `{"_id": {"_data": "....:}}`.

Because of that I am not able to plug in Elasticsearch sink connector.

Anybody has a solution for it?

Thank you,

Francesco

Comment: Where did you get this config from? Usually it's `key.converter`, not `key.serializer` etc